# HTTP request failing in AWS Lambda function for Alexa

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to return data from an external api in my inline Lambda function but when I test this in the developer console for Alexa, I get 'There was a problem with the requested skills response' and I can't work out why.
Also, as I am doing this from the AWS console, I can't console.log to see what it actually being returned.
(I have removed the default intents for the sake of the post)

```
const request = require('request');

const handlers = {
'LaunchRequest': function () {
    this.emit(':ask', 'Welcome');
},
'GiveUpdateIntent': function (){
    var slot = this.event.request.intent.slots.line.value;

    httpGet(slot, (theResult) => {
            this.response.speak(theResult);
            this.emit(':responseReady');
        });

}

};
function httpGet(query, callback) {
var options = {
    host: 'api.tfl.gov.uk',
    path: '/line/' + encodeURIComponent(query) + '/status',
    method: 'GET',
};

var req = http.request(options, res => {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    var responseString = "";

    //accept incoming data asynchronously
    res.on('data', chunk => {
        responseString += chunk;
    });

    //return the data when streaming is complete
    res.on('end', () => {
        console.log(responseString[0]);
        callback(responseString[0]);
    });

});
req.end();
}


exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
    const alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context, callback);
    alexa.APP_ID = APP_ID;
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
    alexa.execute();
};
```

Comment: *"Also, as I am doing this from the aws console, I can't Console.log to see what it actually being returned."*  Why not?

Comment: I'm not sure why but even when I run very simple code that I know works, console.log never shows up in my console.

Comment: That is unexpected.  Possibly an issue with the permissions on your Lambda execution role.

Comment: Ahh, I can see come console.log outputs in the log files

Comment: I just answered a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51764274/how-to-make-an-asynchronous-api-call-for-alexa-skill-application-with-a-lambda-f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be with using http itself instead of https.

The only response back that I was getting was a status code of 302 which is a redirection because the api I was calling changes all http requests to https.

Therefore, I changed my import to https and used the https.get method (instead of http.get) to call the api and the correct response was returned.

Answer (score 1):

***"There was a problem with the requested skills response"*** generally means that the response from your skill was not in the expected format.

Your API request

Ex: vicotria

```
https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line/victoria/Status
```

returns a JSON, and you can't directly pass it Alexa as response. Before you send it back to Alexa, take out `status` that you actually want Alexa to speak. Then put that into a meaningful sentence that any skill user will understand and send it back.

For example you can return something like:

```
var speech = "Status severity description for " + 
              this.event.request.intent.slots.line.value +
              " is "
              + responseBody[0].lineStatuses.statusSeverityDescription;
this.emit(':ask',speech, "your re-prompt here");
```

This is a sample JSON that I got

```
[
  {
    "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Line, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
    "id": "victoria",
    "name": "Victoria",
    "modeName": "tube",
    "disruptions": [],
    "created": "2018-07-31T12:11:08.477Z",
    "modified": "2018-07-31T12:11:08.477Z",
    "lineStatuses": [
      {
        "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineStatus, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
        "id": 0,
        "statusSeverity": 10,
        "statusSeverityDescription": "Good Service",
        "created": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "validityPeriods": []
      }
    ],
    "routeSections": [],
    "serviceTypes": [
      {
        "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineServiceTypeInfo, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
        "name": "Regular",
        "uri": "/Line/Route?ids=Victoria&serviceTypes=Regular"
      },
      {
        "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineServiceTypeInfo, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
        "name": "Night",
        "uri": "/Line/Route?ids=Victoria&serviceTypes=Night"
      }
    ],
    "crowding": {
      "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Crowding, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities"
    }
  }
]
```

**CloudWatch**: 
Always make use of CloudWatch to see the logs of your Lambda function, you will get a link under `Monitoring` tab of your Lambda Function.

**Configuring Lambda Test Events**: You can test you Lambda code right from your inline editor by configuring `Lambda Test Events` under `Test` menu of your inline editor. A function can have up to 10 test events.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this but still no result. This is what I get from the log:
 2018-08-02T09:44:55.475Z b5e52be3-9638-11e8-bcc9-c3e178d35a1f 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'locale' of undefined

at AlexaRequestEmitter.HandleLambdaEvent (/var/task/node_modules/alexa-sdk/lib/alexa.js:112:38)

at AlexaRequestEmitter.value (/var/task/node_modules/alexa-sdk/lib/alexa.js:100:31)

at exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:80:11)

Comment: what is there in line number 80 of index.js ?

Comment: It's the alexa.exeute();. The last line in the code above

Comment: What is the test JSON you are using.

Comment: its this: {
  "key3": "value3",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key1": "value1"
} not sure if i need to change anything herre

Comment: Yes, use the actual JSON generated in Alexa test simulator.

Comment: Lambda test JSON should  be like mocking the actual request that your Lambda function will receive from the skill.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177275/discussion-between-callum-and-cicil-thomas).

Comment: This answer started correctly about why Alexa is answering that.  But the root cause is not the one you mention.  Root cause is because http get call is asynchronous and the handler does return no response.  The HTTP Get callback is called after the handler did return.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your `handler` is returning before the callback is called.  I strongly suggest to move away from callback based development in NodeJS and to use `Promise` instead.

I just answered a similar question, and provided sample code with promises.  Check it here [How to make an asynchronous api call for Alexa Skill application with a Lambda function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51764274/how-to-make-an-asynchronous-api-call-for-alexa-skill-application-with-a-lambda-f)