# How to make an asynchronous api call for Alexa Skill application with a Lambda function?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I want to call an api from a Lambda function. My handler is triggered by an intent which includes two required slots. Therefore I don't know in advance whether I will be returning a `Dialog.Delegate` directive or my response from the api request. How do I promise these return values by the time the intent handler is called?

This is my handler:

```
const FlightDelayIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'MyIntent';
  },

  handle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;

    if (request.dialogState != "COMPLETED"){
      return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .addDelegateDirective(request.intent)
        .getResponse();
    } else {
      // Make asynchronous api call, wait for the response and return.
      var query = 'someTestStringFromASlot';

      httpGet(query,  (result) => {
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
          .speak('I found something' + result)
          .reprompt('test')
          .withSimpleCard('Hello World', 'test')
          .getResponse();
      });
    }
  },
};
```

This is my helper function which makes the request:

```
const https = require('https');

function httpGet(query, callback) {
    var options = {
        host: 'myHost',
        path: 'someTestPath/' + query,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'theId': 'myId'
        }
    };

    var req = https.request(options, res => {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        var responseString = "";

        //accept incoming data asynchronously
        res.on('data', chunk => {
            responseString = responseString + chunk;
        });

        //return the data when streaming is complete
        res.on('end', () => {
            console.log('==> Answering: ');
            callback(responseString);
        });

    });
    req.end();
}
```

So I suspect I will have to use promises and put an "async" in front of my handle function? I am very new to all of this so I don't know the implications of this, especially considering the fact that I have two different return values, one directly and the other one delayed. How would I solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspected, your handler code is finishing before the asynchronous call to http.request, hence the Alexa SDK receives no return value from the `handle` function and will return an invalid response to Alexa.

I slightly modified your code to run it locally on a laptop to illustrate the issue :

```
const https = require('https');

function httpGet(query, callback) {
    var options = {
        host: 'httpbin.org',
        path: 'anything/' + query,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'theId': 'myId'
        }
    };

    var req = https.request(options, res => {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        var responseString = "";

        //accept incoming data asynchronously
        res.on('data', chunk => {
            responseString = responseString + chunk;
        });

        //return the data when streaming is complete
        res.on('end', () => {
            console.log('==> Answering: ');
            callback(responseString);
        });

    });
    req.end();
}

function FlightDelayIntentHandler() {

    // canHandle(handlerInput) {
    //   return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
    //     && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'MyIntent';
    // },

    // handle(handlerInput) {
    //   const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;

    // if (request.dialogState != "COMPLETED"){
    //     return handlerInput.responseBuilder
    //       .addDelegateDirective(request.intent)
    //       .getResponse();
    //   } else {
        // Make asynchronous api call, wait for the response and return.
        var query = 'someTestStringFromASlot';

        httpGet(query,  (result) => {
            console.log("I found something " + result);

        //   return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        //     .speak('I found something' + result)
        //     .reprompt('test')
        //     .withSimpleCard('Hello World', 'test')
        //     .getResponse();
        });

        console.log("end of function reached before httpGet will return");
    //   }
    // }
}

FlightDelayIntentHandler();
```

To run this code, do not forget `npm install http` , then `node test.js`.  It produces

```
stormacq:~/Desktop/temp $ node test.js
end of function reached before httpGet will return
==> Answering:
I found something {
  "args": {},
  "data": "",
...
```

So, the key is to wait for `http get` to return before to return a response to Alexa. For that, I propose to modify your `httpGet` function to return a promise instead using callbacks.

Modified code is like this (I kept your original code as comment)

```
const https = require('https');

async function httpGet(query) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        var options = {
            host: 'httpbin.org',
            path: 'anything/' + query,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'theId': 'myId'
            }
        };

        var req = https.request(options, res => {
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            var responseString = "";

            //accept incoming data asynchronously
            res.on('data', chunk => {
                responseString = responseString + chunk;
            });

            //return the data when streaming is complete
            res.on('end', () => {
                console.log('==> Answering: ');
                resolve(responseString);
            });

            //should handle errors as well and call reject()!
        });
        req.end();

    });

}



async function FlightDelayIntentHandler() {

        // canHandle(handlerInput) {
    //   return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
    //     && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'MyIntent';
    // },

    // handle(handlerInput) {
    //   const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;

    // if (request.dialogState != "COMPLETED"){
    //     return handlerInput.responseBuilder
    //       .addDelegateDirective(request.intent)
    //       .getResponse();
    //   } else {
        // Make asynchronous api call, wait for the response and return.
        var query = 'someTestStringFromASlot';

        var result = await httpGet(query);
        console.log("I found something " + result);

        //   return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        //     .speak('I found something' + result)
        //     .reprompt('test')
        //     .withSimpleCard('Hello World', 'test')
        //     .getResponse();
        //});

        console.log("end of function reached AFTER httpGet will return");
    //   }
    // }
}

FlightDelayIntentHandler();
```

Running this code produces :

```
stormacq:~/Desktop/temp $ node test.js
==> Answering:
I found something{
  "args": {},
  "data": "",
...
end of function reached AFTER httpGet will return
```