# returning a value after resolving a promise to use in alexa

Tags: javascript, promise, alexa-skills-kit

I have read this answer: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

I have used .done in the end and it does not work.

I am trying to return a value from a promise and store it after a promise is resolved.

If i console.log the result, it works but when I try to return the value, i get a pending promise.

```
function getpassphrase() {
  return client.getItem('user-passphrase')
  .setHashKey('user','-1035827551964454856')
  .selectAttributes(['user', 'passphrase'])
  .execute()
  .then(function (data) {
    return data.result.passphrase;
  })
};


const y = getpassphrase()
.done(function(r) {
    return r;
    //if i do console.log(r) it gives the actual result
  })

console.log(y);
```

I have tried async await as well:

```
const x = (async function(){
    const y = await getpassphrase();
    return x
})();
```

I run into the same issue.. the x value is a promise pending here..but console.log gives the actual value..

expected: 'abc' actual: 'undefined'

This goes into my alexa handler which when used inside a then function is throwing a 'unhandled response error'

```
const passPhraseIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
        && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'getPassPhraseIntent';
},
handle(handlerInput) {

async function getpassphrase(){
    return (await client.getItem('user-passphrase')
    .setHashKey('user','-1035827551964454856')
    .selectAttributes(['user', 'passphrase'])
    .execute()
    .then(function (data) {
        return data.result.passphrase;
    }));
}

(async function(){
    let passphrase_db = await getpassphrase();

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak(speechText2)
        .getResponse();
    })();

  }
};
```

Comment: `handle()` can be `async` https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/4a46da08-d1b8-4d8e-9277-055307a9bf4a/alexa-skill-recipe-update-call-and-get-data-from-external-apisblog or [callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51764274/how-to-make-an-asynchronous-api-call-for-alexa-skill-application-with-a-lambda-f). Also `done()` is only for jQuery, just keep that in mind.

Comment: I am unfortunately getting an alexa unhandled response error:     handle(handlerInput) { (async function(){
            let passphrase_db = await getpassphrase();
        
            return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                .speak(passphrase_db)
                .getResponse();
        })(); }

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not do the process inside the ``then`` block itself?

Comment: i tried both async and then.. alexa returns an error if i send the response out from inside the then or async block.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how promises work, you can only access the resolved value after a then block and you cannot return from an async task.

Comment: i know this much that we have to use a then block and write everything to do with the promise return inside the 'then' block.. but i was wondering if there is any way to pull the return out to be used outside.. so i am concluding that there is no way to do this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to return a value outside of a then block or outside of an async function.. thanks a lot everyone for taking your time in responding to my question :) much appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Use [async-await](https://javascript.info/async-await) inside an IIFE :

```
(async (){
  const y = await getpassphrase();
  console.log(y);
})();
```

Comment: I tried it.. console.log(y) works but if i try to do something like this:   const x = (async function(){
    const y = await getpassphrase();
    return y
  })();

Comment: Will wrapping the whole thing in a promise (inside the function) and resolving after the then block when the successful response is received work? After that, function call with a then block should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use async await, which is the current standard for handling promises/asynchronous functionality.

Define the logic you have here within the context of an asynchronous function, and then use "await" to pause until completion of the promise and unwrap the value.

```
async function sample() {
    const y = await getpassphrase();
    console.log(y); //abc
}
```

Comment: I am using alexa so I am not able to push alexa handlers into an async function.. it has to be used outside the async functions.. there is no way to return a value from an async function? sounds terrible to me.. p.s. i am new to javascript

Comment: Can you add some more context to your question? I don't think we have enough information to handle your question the way you need. 

It would also be a good idea to read up on javascript, because it seems like you're not at all familiar how asynchronous calls are handled in Javascript.